# marginRight property of imageview not working

Tags: android, imageview

I have an image view whose background is a xml shape  drawable i.e. a rectangle shape drawable.My app's orientation   is fixed to landscape view.

The imageview is in relative layout.

I  am trying to move it to  the right of the screen by setting the appropriate value of layout_marginRight but this does not work .The imageView always stays in its's original position.

I have tried the following other options also but none helped.

The other options which I tried are:

1. Creating a new relative layout params and  setting the right margin
2. Creating new margin layout params and setting the position
3. Trying padding option
4. Setting the imageview to  right position relative to another imageview...
5. Using display metrics to get width of screen and accordingly setting the margin....

I am stuck since a week setting the position of this imageview...

I was thinking the best approach is to  set this imageview in between two imageview as I am not able to move it by setting margin but that does not work either...

Here is the current xml of my imageview in main.xml:-

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rect1"
            android:background="@drawable/rect"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried android:gravity??

Comment: can u pls the layout in which the image view exist..

Comment: This is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13132675/1237297 :) It works, I have tested it.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see why adding a margin to the right of the image would help move the image to the right, it just extends the right side bounds of the imageview by the margin. As long as the imageview isn't actually on the right side of the parentview, it would be allowed to grow without changing position. I suggest using `layout_alignParentRight="true"` on the imageview if you want it on the right of your relativelayout, and then you can use the marginRight to control how far off the right side you want it.

Comment: I tried this option also, but it did not work...what it does is positions the imageview to the rightmost edge but marginRight does not work...

Comment: well, if this doesnt work, you ought to update your question with a more detailed view of the problem; its mostly speculative now.

Answer (score 1):

Make the layout_width attribute of the RelativeLayout to fill_parent and see it work :)

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that my parent layout's width was set to `wrap_content`, which doesn't have a defined width during the editor, I think. Thus, I couldn't use `marginRight` to get an offset. I had to change the width to a fixed size like `match_parent` or a constant dp size.

Answer (score -2):

put the image view in a linearlayout, then use   android:layout_marginRight="70dp

Comment: @Vic I tried gravity to right  but still marginRight property is not setting the right margin