# android:layout_marginRight attribute not working on RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an Inner relative layout with 2 images, and when I set the android:layout_marginRight
attribute it doesn't do anything.

Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/location_image_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="69.33dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want the top image to be to the left of the second image and align it to the bottom of the second image.

Comment: There are a lot of good answers. Its a good practice to upvote responses you like.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is in the layout's property `android:layout_width`. When it is set to `"wrap_content"`,the `android:layout_marginRight` won't working, but rather, only when it is set to `"fill_parent"`, the `android:layout_marginRight` will work.

Comment: in 2017: you can use android:layout_marginEnd if API >= 17. And since API 8 we should use "match_parent" not "fill_parent".

Answer (score 1):

You have used the following thats why it is happening

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

just remove this line you will get the margin from the right in your imageview..

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/location_image_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="69.33dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icone"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Try this. It work for me and exact that you want

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    ...
/>
```

I encounter the same problem and if you change the parent RelativeLayout's layout_width to "match_parent" it works. Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score -5):

Try to use LinerarLayout instead of RelativeLayout for applying Margin in your Layout.